# How do you disable no-plusplus when using eslint?

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

When using eslint in Visual Studio Code, AirBnB style Ubuntu Linux, no-plusplus is enabled as default so using ++ for example in a for loop will error: [eslint] Unary operator '++' used. (no-plusplus)

How do you disable that setting?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can just override it in your `.eslintrc.js` file as follows:

```
'no-plusplus': 'off'
```

or if you don't want to disable it completely but only for `for-loops`:

```
'no-plusplus': [2, { allowForLoopAfterthoughts: true }]
```

Comment: Do I need to surround this with anything? I'm getting this error: `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 'no-plusplus': 'off'
                                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: For newer versions of ESLint, use `"allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true`, as explained on the docs: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus#options

Comment: You can simple write <variable> += 1 instead, as suggested by ESLint.

Answer (score 21):

You can also write `variable += 1` instead, [as suggested by ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus).

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Comment: @БагдаулетСайын except it doesn't even answer the question ...

Answer (score 2):

You can locate the file location you need to alter on Linux by searching for the keyword using grep, in this case to search for the file containing plusplus when in the folder eslint was installed use

`grep -r plusplus`

The correct file will be the eslint-config file, in this case it should be: node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/style.js

To disable the setting comment out the no-plusplus line, you can easily re-enable if required:

```
// 'no-plusplus': 'error',
```

Comment: editing a file in node_modules shouldn't be considered the "correct way" to do something

Answer (score 2):

Or you can go like this:

```
'no-plusplus': 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write your declared **variable += 1** instead, as suggested by ESLint.

```
varible++ is similar as variable+=1.
```

Comment: This answer was already suggested prior to your answer by Fabian? Some users may down-vote this as it is not adding anything new and removing credit from Fabian, suggest removing